# Solving an exponential inequality problem

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

How do I prove the following inequality :

$$\Bigg(\frac{2}{\alpha^2} \, \big( e^{\alpha x} - e^{\alpha y} \big) \, + \, e^{\alpha y} (y^2 - x^2) \; \Bigg) > 0 $$

given, $x, y > 0$ ?

Can anyone provide me with hints about this problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Here, $\alpha$ is a **positive constant**.

Comment: The word you're looking for here is "inequality."

Comment: This is obviously false, try $x=y+1$ when $y\to\infty$.

Comment: "Obviously"?lol